# Trying to parse packets in Python and struggling to build a proper script

Tags: python, parsing, packet

I have a huge (like 600MB) file of packet captures in the following format:

```
[S->C][02][0x5A97BE]
[0047F32B] 95 DE 5E 52 4A F3 80 F5 47 18 97 70 10 EE 5B E5  ..^RJ...G..p..[.
           7C E8 F5 B2 2F 1F 3A 6B A1 8F 6C 73 65 A6 42 27  |.../.:k..lse.B'
```

My goal is to reduce this entire thing so it looks like this:

```
[S->C][02][0x5A97BE]
95DE5E524AF380F54718977010EE5BE57CE8F5B22F1F3A6BA18F6C7365A64227
```

I looked through some string.split() and regex tutorials but none of them seemed to quite get me there.  Basically I am trying to make an if statement checking if the line contains [S->C] or has a ">" in the fourth character spot.  If so, skip line.  Then I want to remove everything to the left of the first space and everything to the right of the double space (there's a double space between the hex and ascii display.)

I have followed like 3 tutorials now, modified them, and just can't get it to parse correctly.  Any help would be amazing. I know it isn't too hard but for some reason it's eluding me.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way. Pass the input file as `myfun(input_file)`

```
def myfun(in_file):
    header = True
    # Get the meat, remove newlines.
    reg1 = re.compile(r'^.{11}(.{47}).*\n')
    # Remove spaces.
    reg2 = re.compile(r' ')
    with open(in_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if header:
                # Print the header.
                print(line, end='')
                header = False
            else:
                # Print the body.
                print(reg2.sub('', reg1.sub('\g<1>', line)), end='')
    # Append a newline.
    print()
    return
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it does exactly what I need!  I just really need to get a better handle on regex I guess.

Comment: You're welcome. There's a single regex that can eliminate the `if n==0...` part but I'm not sure it's better because it's harder to grok and probably more computationally expensive.